# How to create swagger document for unknown type using OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, openapi

I am trying to **build swagger document from asp.net core api** application. Issue I am facing is my response object **ProductResponse** (see below for detail) **which has IEnumerable of string** as property.

> String is JSON object

which could be anything (unknown type) (different key/value).

How can I build swagger document **for unknown type using OpenAPI 3.0. Any advice?**

Response Object like below

```
{
  "items": [
    "string"
  ]
}
```

**WebApi .Net core Code as below**

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Get product
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>product</remarks>
    /// <param name="RequestDto"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <response code="200">Successful Response</response>
    /// <response code="400">Bad Request</response>
    /// <response code="401">Unauthorized</response>
    /// <response code="424">Failed Dependency</response>
    /// <response code="500">Internal Server Error</response>
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProductResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), StatusCodes.Status424FailedDependency)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [HttpGet(Name = "getProduct")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]Request RequestDto)
    {
       ....some code here.
    }

public class ProductResponse
{
 [JsonPropertyName("data")]
 public IEnumerable<string> data { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

Comment: Hello, did you tried the solution provided? Feel free to let me know if you still need any furthr assistance on this.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I build swagger document for unknown type using OpenAPI 3.0.
> Any advice?

As we know swagger has following  `data type` up to now.

```
string (this includes dates and files)
number
integer
boolean
array
object
```

Thorefore, A schema which doesn't matches within the above mentioned `data-type` are called [`Any Type`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#any)

[image]

**Note:** If you need any further information please refer to this [`offical document here`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#any)